# Deployment failed because no Windows Phone 8 phone was detected. Make sure a phone is connected and powered on

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone

I wrote first app using `VS2012`, Its giving error although I did attach my phone.

> Error 1 Deployment failed because no Windows Phone 8 phone was
>   detected. Make sure a phone is connected and powered on

Answer (score 3):

I disconnected the Phone from the USB. Then went to 'Control Panel->Hardware and Sound->Devices' and Removed Device. Then connected the Phone to the USB.
I was the able to Register the Phone and Run the app.